# Rails - undefined method 'reflections' exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Calling really_destroy! on an active record in order to hard delete the record throws the following exception. How can I resolve this?

https://github.com/radar/paranoia

```
myRecord.really_destroy!
```

NoMethodError: undefined method 'reflections' for #MyActiveRecord:0x00000102793aa8

from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@company/gems/activemodel-4.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Paranoia library which is fixed on the latest version. It was due to a change in ActiveModel where reflections method is no longer an instance method, rather it's now a class method